# sum of rows in multiple join

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I am trying to row sum  for  multiple join. I am able to find it only for single table  , I have used following query .

```
SELECT sd.Descrip
    ,0 AS TotalLedgerNumber
    ,ss.Total
FROM tblServiceSummary ss
LEFT JOIN servdesc sd ON ss.Service_time = sd.ServDescID
JOIN funct fn ON fn.FunctID = ss.FunctionID
GROUP BY sd.Descrip

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Total'
    ,SUM(IFNULL(NULL, 0)) AS TotalLedgerNumber
    ,sum(ss.Total)
FROM tblServiceSummary ss
LEFT JOIN servdesc sd ON ss.Service_time = sd.ServDescID
JOIN funct fn ON fn.FunctID = ss.FunctionID
WHERE fn.StartDate BETWEEN "2018-9-18"
        AND "2018-9-18"
GROUP BY sd.Descrip
```

this gives me result like this

[image]

i want to show sum of all the above displayed rows along with all rows

i tried to add remove group by and where in upper and lower queries .if i tried to remove group by from lower ..it shows like Total | null | null  but this is not working . Please suggest

Comment: What is your expected output ? and some sample data would be helpful! Question wording is not clear

Comment: expected output is sum of all the above mentioned rows

Comment: Can you post expected output also. Sum of all rows can be determined at application code level itself.

Comment: i dont want at application code level

Comment: In that case, you need to post your expected table output (either as a picture or a table). Currently, it is not making sense!

Comment: what is not making sense . sum of above rows is not clear to you ?

Comment: Just remove your group by in the lower query. Run that query BY ITSELF and see if it gives you a single record that contains the total. If so, then it will work fine in the UNION to do what you want.

Comment: it is showing /...............Total  | null | null  .......

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to SUM all rows after a Group, you can encapsulate your query and SUM after it.

Example:

```
SELECT
   SUM(Descrip)
FROM
   (

SELECT sd.Descrip
    ,0 AS TotalLedgerNumber
    ,ss.Total
FROM tblServiceSummary ss
LEFT JOIN servdesc sd ON ss.Service_time = sd.ServDescID
JOIN funct fn ON fn.FunctID = ss.FunctionID
GROUP BY sd.Descrip

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Total'
    ,SUM(IFNULL(NULL, 0)) AS TotalLedgerNumber
    ,sum(ss.Total)
FROM tblServiceSummary ss
LEFT JOIN servdesc sd ON ss.Service_time = sd.ServDescID
JOIN funct fn ON fn.FunctID = ss.FunctionID
WHERE fn.StartDate BETWEEN "2018-9-18"
        AND "2018-9-18"
GROUP BY sd.Descrip

) summedRows
```